# AVR PINx.n not working

Tags: avr

I have the folloving code:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void) {
    DDRB = 0xFF;//B output
    DDRD = 0x00;//D input
    PORTB = 0x00;//LED off
    PORTD = 0xFF;//Pull-ups activated
    while(1) {
    if(PIND.4==0) {
        PORTB &= ~(1<<PB0); /* LED on */
        _delay_ms(100);
        PORTB |= 1<<PB0; /* LED off */
        _delay_ms(100);
    }}
    return 0;
}
```

However, when trying to build it in Atmel Studio it gives an error:

```
Error   1   expected ')' before numeric constant
```

The line number refers to the line `if(PIND.4==0) {`
If I remove the point between 'PIND' and '4' it builds but the program won't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PIND.4` style of register access might not be defined in your particular `ioXXXX.h` file.

An easy replacement is

```
if(PIND & (1<<4) == 0) {
```

Comment: I do not believe that it is defined in *any* of the AVR headers.

Comment: That style is described in many sources. Like there: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1rmB6VRZoC46RKIF8Wp4n4IfMHdYZIkggmYX1fjA0IBY/preview?slide=id.p26

Comment: "Featuring programming with CodeVision AVR C Compiler"